# How to get average of multiple time series

Tags: charts, visualization

I have few computers running. I want to get the average CPU usage of these computers and plot it as a graph. So I've collected CPU usage in regular intervals in these machines. So for each computer I have a data set of time and CPU usage.

But the times at which CPU measurements are taken in different machines are not in sync. For example in 1st machine CPU may be measured in time 1, 5, 9. In the second machine CPU may be measured in time 2, 5, 8. I want to get an average data series from these different data sets. Could you point me to some resources?

Thanks - Supun.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Supun! Can you supply us with an actual sample of how your data looks, not "1, 5, 9", etc.? That way we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a process to bucket your data to the time period you want to report on. Depending on what your time measurements represent the CPU data would go in the same bucket. For example time 1 and 2 might go in bucket one, times 3 and 4 in bucket 2 etc.

We do something similar with survey data. Responses may come in over the course of many days or even weeks. To report trend data we roll up the data into day, week or month time periods.